# Using java thread annotations on kotlin properties

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, annotations

I am using java annotations @UiThread @AnyThread @WorkerThread that help me to better understand my code and also notify me not supposed thread call of method. Howwhere there is BIG limitations that ruins whole purpose that I cannnot use them on properties:

```
@UiThread
val order get() = value.order
```

Gives:

> This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property without
> backing field or delegate'

Is there no any other library with some preprocessor or anything other that just solve this little issue ? This looks to me like unfinished language feature. Looks like they where not supposed for kotlin maybe ? So kotlin has no way of being working with this correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

```
@get:UiThread
val order get() = value.order
```

or

```
val order @UiThread get() = value.order
```